# Spring HATEOAS resourcesupport -> domain object

Tags: java, spring, hateoas, spring-hateoas

While serving objects we use toResource method to transform them into resources and on the way back (posting a resource representation from client to server) how can I transform the representation back to the domain object?

I want to construct Book(@Entity) class from BookResource(extends ResourceSupport) class.

```
@RequestMapping(path="/", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/vnd.company.app.book-v1+hal+json")
    public ResponseEntity<?> addBook(@RequestBody BookResource bookResource) {
        //What to do here?
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your BookResource should extend [Resource](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.18.x/api/org/springframework/hateoas/Resource.html) rather than ResourceSupport.

```
public class BookResource extends Resource<Book> {

    public BookResource(Book content, Link... links) {
        super(content, links);
    }

}
```

That way, you get the [getContent()](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.18.x/api/org/springframework/hateoas/Resource.html#getContent--) method for free, which "Returns the underlying entity."

Comment: Spring docs give example to extend ResourceSupport?http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-hateoas/0.20.x/reference/html/#fundamentals.resources

Comment: `Resource` is a direct descendant of `ResourceSupport`, so by extending `Resource`, you extend `ResourceSupport`, and also get access to the domain object, which is what you asked for.